# Getting error while sum of columns with alias Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL. I have a table called `management`. I'm trying to write a query like below:

```
SELECT
    registerd, Appeared, registerd + Appeared AS col3 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(REGDNO) AS registerd, branch_code,
         SUM(CASE WHEN SUB1_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB1_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR
                       SUB2_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB1_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR
                       SUB2_GRADE <> 'Ab ' AND SUB2_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR
                       SUB3_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB3_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR 
                       SUB4_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB4_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR  
                       SUB5_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB5_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR 
                       SUB6_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB6_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR 
                       SUB7_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB7_GRADE IS NOT NULL
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Appeared
     FROM 
         MANAGEMENT) AS subQueryAlias 
GROUP BY
    BRANCH_CODE
```

but I am getting the following error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Column 'MANAGEMENT.BRANCH_CODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `group by` clause should be part of the inner subquery, not the outer query:

```
SELECT  registered, appeared, registered + appeared AS col3 
FROM    (SELECT   branch_code,
                  COUNT(regdno) AS registered,
                  SUM(CASE WHEN sub1_grade <> 'Ab' AND sub1_grade IS NOT NULL OR 
                                sub2_grade <> 'Ab' AND sub1_grade IS NOT NULL OR 
                                sub2_grade <> 'Ab' AND sub2_grade IS NOT NULL OR 
                                sub4_grade <> 'Ab' AND sub3_grade IS NOT NULL OR 
                                sub4_grade <> 'Ab' AND sub4_grade IS NOT NULL OR 
                                sub5_grade <> 'Ab' AND sub5_grade IS NOT NULL OR 
                                sub6_grade <> 'Ab' AND sub6_grade IS NOT NULL OR
                                sub7_grade <> 'Ab' AND sub7_grade IS NOT NULL
                           THEN 1 
                           ELSE 0
                      END) AS appeared
         FROM     management
         GROUP BY branch_code) AS subQueryAlias
```

Comment: As a general note, having lots of fields like your `SUB#_GRADE` fields does not work well in practice. Try and read about normalisation and one-to-many relationships in databases. It will make your SQL easier.

Comment: sir can u suggest me for above query  how to normalize sum case please